# Cannot install Pynput, or Keyboard

Tags: python, linux, pip, raspberry-pi, pynput

I am trying to install Pynput or keyboard for help with a keyboard interface, and when I use

```
pip install pynput
```

or

```
pip3 install pynput
```

It says it successfully installs, and then when I go to a Python IDE and put in

```
import pynput
```

it says

```
Traceback (most recent call last): 
  File "<pyshell>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No Module named 'pynput'
```

So if anyone can help me thank you

Comment: The Python you used to install pynput *must be the same* Python you use to run your app. What is this Python IDE? Maybe it's using a different Python version or it's using a virtual environment. If it's using a virtual env, you need to install pynput using the IDE.

Comment: @GinoMempin or just activate the venv from the command line first.

Answer (score 1):

It should work if you do

```
python3 -m pip install pynput
```

Comment: Please add more context or official documentation explaining why to use the command instead of the OP's

Answer (score 0):

Check your Python IDE's version, then do this in the command prompt:

```
py -{yourVersion} -m pip install pynput
```

note: {yourVersion} is only the major and minor version. For example if you're running 3.7.3, then type it `py -3.7 -m pip install pynput` rather than `py -3.7.3 -m pip install pynput`

close then re-run the same version of the IDE you've run before.

```
import pynput
```

it should solve your problem.